# Why is the unit circle a nullset?

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure

I need to show that the unit circle $S=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2=1\}$ is a nullset.

My Idea was the following. Let us take a point $(x_i,y_i)\in S$. Then we can define a square $$Q_i=\left[x_i,x_i+\frac{1}{k}\right)\times \left[y_i,y_i+\frac{1}{k}\right)$$for some $k\in \Bbb{N}$. Then clearly $(x_i,y_i)\in Q_i$. Therefore by the monotonicity of the measure $$\lambda(\{(x_i,y_i)\})\leq \lambda(Q_i)=\frac{1}{k^2}\stackrel{k\rightarrow \infty}{\rightarrow}0$$Now we can cover $S$ with such $Q_i$'s and get that $$\lambda(S)\leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty \lambda(Q_i)=0$$ and thus we know that $S$ is a nullset

Does this works or is this completly wrong?

Thanks for your help

Comment: a null set *respect to the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^2$*. To see why you can show that there exists sets of arbitrarily small measure, that contains your set. Your reasoning would work as far you show that your sets cover the ring. Its easier to just use annuli that cover the ring, annuli of arbitrarily small width

Comment: sorry I don't understand your answer. So my proof doesn't work?

Comment: I see this with the annulus, but we couldn't use this because they told us that we are in a measure theory course and there we defined the lebesque measure over $n$-dimensional cuboids.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that you can list the points $(x_i,y_i) \in S$ using an integer valued index $I \in \{1,2,3,...\}$. However, that is not possible,  the set $S$ has uncountably many points.

Comment: @LeeMosher yes I also thought about that have you any hint?

Comment: I thought mayby one can use that $S$ is compact?

Comment: "we defined the lebesque measure over n-dimensional cuboids." -- Could always show formally that this still gives the desired area for a circle and then use the annulus argument.

Comment: sorry I hardly can imagine how to show this formally that the area of the circle can also be computed by cuboids

Comment: @aprozz you can cover $S$ by attaching an arbitrarily small open cuboid centered on every point, then select a finite subcover because $S$ is compact. This will allow you to index them and show that they become vanishingly small.

Comment: @cyclotomicfield thanks for your answer. So I should define $$Q_i=\left(x_i,x_i+1/k\right) \times \left (y_i,y_i+1/k\right) $$ instead of the product of two halfopen intervalls. Then this is clearly a covering and as you said since $S$ is closed and bounded in $\Bbb{R}^2$ by Heine borel it is also compact. Thus we have a fintie subcover $$\bigcup_{i=1}^m Q_i\supset S$$ and therefore $$\lambda(S)\leq \sum_{i=1}^m \lambda(Q_i)= \sum_{i=1}^m \frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{m}{k^2}\rightarrow 0$$ does this works now?

Comment: That doesn't work, but the problem is very subtle: the value of $m$ (from the finite covering) depends on $k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try to use your approach of doing it by hand using squares. We will try to be really efficient with the squares, while still covering the whole circle. For this, note that if $A=(x, y)$ and $A'=(x', y')$ are two points in the circle, then their distance is bounded above by $|\theta|$, where $\theta$ is the angle between them. (There are many ways to check this. One way is to draw a picture, and note that the triangle $AA'O$ (where $O=(0,0)$) is isosceles whose top angle is $|\theta|$. Then use trigonometry to bound the distance between $A$ and $A'$ by $2\sin(|\theta|/2) \leq |\theta|$.)

This way, fix an integer $k$. Let $A_1=(x_1, y_1), \dots, A_k=(x_k, y_k)$ be $k$ points in the plane, dividing the circle in angles of $2\pi/k$. Consider the cubes $Q_i$ centered at $A_i$ and with length $4\pi/k$, so that
$$ Q_i=\left[ x_i - \frac{2\pi}{k}, x_i + \frac{2\pi}{k}\right] \times \left[ y_i - \frac{2\pi}{k}, y_i + \frac{2\pi}{k}\right]$$
Note that they contain all the points whose distance to $A_i$ is less than $\frac{2\pi}{k}$. Also, $\lambda(Q_i)=(4\pi/k)^2=16\pi^2/k^2$.

If $P$ is a point in the circle, then there is some $i$ such that the angle between $A_i$ and $P$ is less than $2\pi/k$, and so the distance between $A_i$ and $P$ is less than $2\pi/k$. Therefore, we get that $P \in Q_i$, and so the $Q_i$ cover the circle.

Now, by monotonicity we get that
$$ \lambda(S) \leq \lambda(Q_1)+\dots+\lambda(Q_k)=k \cdot \frac{16\pi^2}{k^2} = \frac{16\pi^2}{k}. $$
This tends to $0$ when $k \to \infty$, and so $\lambda(S)=0$.

Comment: Aha, okey yes I see. Sorry but shouldn‘t it b $\frac{16\pi^2}{k}$?

Comment: Whoops, yes, I'm sorry

Comment: ah perfect thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\ (f\geq0).$ Then we just need to show its graph $A=\{(x,f(x))|x\in[-1,1]\}$ is a nullset.

Since $f(x)$ is integrable, for $\forall\varepsilon>0,$ there exists a cut $$\pi:-1=x_{0}<x_{1}<\cdots<x_{n}=1$$so that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\omega_{i}\Delta x_{i}<\varepsilon,$ where $$\omega_{i}=M_{i}-m_{i}, M_{i}=\sup_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_{i}]}f(x),m_{i}=\inf_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_{i}]}f(x).$$
Thus$$\{(x,f(x))|x\in[x_{i-1},x_{i}]\}\subset[x_{i-1},x_{i}]\times[m_{i},M_{i}]=I_{i},\ 1\leq i\leq n.$$i.e.$$A\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}I_{i},$$and$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}v(I_{n})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-x_{i-1})(M_{i}-m_{i})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\omega_{i}\Delta x_{i}<\varepsilon,$$
which concludes $A$ is a nullset.